# Setting "auto" width to computed value gives 0, but height works

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

http://11bouchardg.decmultimedia.ca/myriam_coiffure

The problem regards the website linked above.

http://pastebin.com/HyyB9vhL

This is the part of the code that doesn't work as intended. Please look at the comments. Above them are the lines that are problematic.

The code I pointed out with comments intends to replace two elements' height/width value, which is "auto", with its current value in pixels, so I can later do a CSS3 transition - as you might know, the transition property is unable to work with a value of "auto".

Basically, I recover the computed value with this:

```
someVariable=window.getComputedStyle(<"my element">).getPropertyValue('<"width or height">');
```

Then I apply it to the element with this:

```
<"my element">.style.<"width or height">=someVariable;
```

The height works perfectly. The width, however, makes the width 0... which *does* make the CSS3 transition work, but also moves the scissors to the left. You can see how this is a problem by opening a section and closing it again on the page. (You open or close a section by clicking a title.)

Note that getting the computed values is not where the problem lies. As you can see in the pastebin link in the beginning of the message, outputting them with `console.log()` gives the expected values.

> This is the website I'm working on, not an archived copy just for this
>   website. So accessing it after an answer has been accepted will
>   (hopefully!) lead you to a problem-free page. Or a 404 not found
>   error, depending on when you try to access it.

---

**Edit**

Okay, so, since the problem was not very clear, I've created two Fiddles isolating the problem as much as possible. And an explanation drawing.

1 -- WITH content. Will allow you to see how the content's height is properly set according to the stored value. (Yeah, the content doesn't reappear if you reopen the section. Don't feel like looking into this problem since it's not relevant here. Must've removed some important line when I was minimizing the amount of code. And yeah, it's ugly, because I didn't bother to work on the proportions or anything.)

http://jsfiddle.net/ubCB3/1/

2 -- WITHOUT content. This one is so you see only what is directly related to the problem at hand. Yes, it's even uglier, since I minimized the amount of CSS too. The transition is greatly lengthened, so you can see what happens really well.

http://jsfiddle.net/ubCB3/3/

And the explanation drawing. ([Full size here, for reading the small text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy9oi.png)). You can also zoom in with Ctrl-+.
[image: And the explanation drawing is here.]

Comment: Can you isolate the code ( the problem ) and create a fiddle [jsFiddle](www.jsfiddle.com) or something. I'm pretty sure more people will be able to help if you do this.

Comment: I did isolate the code pretty clearly in the Pastebin link (it's just a few lines, all meant to make you understand the purpose of the code, and all important lines are made apparent with a comment). But if it's not enough, I'll make a Fiddle as you ask, later, when I have more time.

Comment: @drinchev I have added a lot of content to the main question. Please tell me you understand the issue, now.

Comment: Your problem doesn't occur on Google Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `max-width : 0` for closing the scissors and `max-width:1000px;` for the opened state. By doing this you override `width:auto` which is the problem in your transition.

Comment: The problem is PRECISELY that I don't want a width of zero for the closed state. I want a width of "auto", directed by the child's width, which is about 0.4em. Besides, the problem is not with how to make the transition work, but with how to properly set my width to its auto value, but explicitly with pixels. Just like I successfully did with the height.

Comment: Not at all. Let me make you a drawing. It should be ready within half an hour.

Comment: Your effect can be written entirely with CSS and selectors. http://jsbin.com/ayewos/4/edit . Your code is too complicated for such a simple transition.

Comment: 1. You're using img tags, which is pretty awful semantically-wise. One of the reasons for the complexity is NOT to use an IMG tag, for which I might lose marks. 2. From what I see in your fiddle, the scissors enlarge the screen when open. 3. Scissors do not have the correct margin.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ayewos/5/ ; 1. it's not a big deal to switch it to something else and set a background : the scissors ; 2. you just have to properly set some margins and place the body in containers ; 3. You can fix that margin, easily too.

Comment: I think I see where you're coming from now... I had misunderstood something. Heck, it's simplifying my code a lot. I'll try that tonight and give you news. Though I'm still super curious as to why the issue I have with my present code is dependent on the browser...

Comment: I just saw something... Your code, by simply using the div scissors and putting a white background-color to it, neglects to make the dashed line apparent between the scissors' blades. That was the reason I had to resort to a "white" div to begin with, because you can't make a background-image overflow its parent, or a background-color not fill its parent. How would you deal with that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29859/discussion-between-drinchev-and-ariane)

Comment: Oh but I just thought of something. A linear-gradient that's basically an abrupt change from white to transparent. Is it doable to tell it to stop "at the scissors" (at X em from the right of the element) instead of "at X%" (which would make it shift from behind the scissors when the width is changed)